# on slave repication filter --replicate-do-db= store; give syntax error 1064 on mysql 5.6

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

--replicate-do-db=store;

CHANGE REPLICATION FILTER replicate_do_db = (store);      //also by using this query

in mysql 5.6 that option on server side give syntax error 1064 how to fix it

Comment: No parentheses.

Comment: also trying without parentheses but still syntax error

Comment: No semicolon on commandline.  No "CHANGE" in my.cnf.  Suggest providing your syntax in context.

Answer (score 0):

That's not available in MySQL 5.6; you edit your my.cnf and restart mysql then it will take effect.